# how does casper help with finality?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, proof-of-stake, consensus, casper

My question is very simple... I've watched some videos and read articles, but couldn't figure this.

It's said that on the internet

> If the block has been finalized, it can't be reverted/changed in casper.

As we know in casper, we have checkpoints and every 100 blocks, we have epoch blocks. Epoch blocks are the ones that validators vote with prepare and commit. So we can sum up that epoch blocks are the ones that get finalized.

If we get back to sentence that is said on the internet, I have a question:

1. does this mean it's that epoch block that can't be reverted ?
2. or all the blocks that come before this epoch block (that has been finalized) can't be reverted/changed ?

If the answer is the second one, then in Hyprid POW+POS of casper(it still follows the longest chain principle), if I broadcast the longest chain, how will it not be accepted by other nodes and validators ?